# mysql dropping database with single quotes in title

Tags: mysql, escaping, single-quotes

So, my python script created a database named 'blabla'. When I try to DROP DATABASE blabla - it doesn't exist. When I try any possible combinations of \'blabla\' "'blabla'" - non of them works and I get syntax error. Using mysql.. Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use backticks to escape special characters:

```
DROP DATABASE `'blabla'`
```